# Creating a lookup field with CSV data in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a look-up field in HTML that uses CSV data. Which is the best way to import the data and how can I pass them into the look-up field?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you be a little more vague please?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: time travel... (I kid. I kid.) But seriously why use csv? storing data in a CSV file poses security risks as well as concurrency (lots of systems dislike multiple users editing the same file if you do it serverside via php, and it's an extra HTTP request if you do it clientside). Why not use a database, or if you want to keep it simple, why not put it in an object literal in your script and ditch the extra file?

Comment: Thanks Jason for your reply. Unfortunately, that's all I have in the specification and I can't deviate from it. So I have a branch of data into CSV file and a simple form on HTML and aim is to make this form working offline. One of the fields of the form has to be a look-up field. That is, when I type a letter (d day), all the relevant data from the CSV file have to be displayed. Now, I'm not really sure how to import the data and make the look-up field working with those data. I created a simple CSV file with more simple data just to get the idea before I get into the hard staff